# lightswitch cannot connect to created database visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lightswitch-2013

Everytime I create new project (only on new project not happening with project I create previously on my campus computer) then add table and screen then I debug i get on the desktop application show red x mark and "UNABLE TO LOAD DATA. PLEASE CHECK YOUR NETWORK CONNECTION" and on visual studio:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.

on Application1\Application1\Application1.Server\GeneratedArtifacts\ApplicationDataObjectContext.cs 

    public ApplicationData(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "ApplicationData")
            {
                OnContextCreated();
            }

inside connectionString
```

is

```
"metadata=res://Application.Server/ApplicationData.csdl|res://Application.Server/ApplicationData.ssdl|res://Application.Server/ApplicationData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
connection string=\"Data
Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='E:..Desktop\\Application1\\Application1\\Bin\\Data\\ApplicationDatabase.mdf';Integrated
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True\""
```

I'm running visual studio update 1 then I uninstall update 1. I try to uninstall visual studio and install it again but no result. I am on win7 pro sp 1 (x64)

---

Update :

i try to reinstall windows (still using win7pro sp1) and install vs2013 and stil get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recently i found that changing location of my user folder ("C:\Users\your username" ex desktop ,document,download ) from its default location make visual studio generate connection string to iis express server wrong. moving your user folder in win 8 make you cannot run win phone 8 emulator in visual studio